# NullPointerException While adding JLabel to JPanel

Tags: java, arrays, swing, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

Im getting this strange NullpointerException whilst adding a JLabel to a JPanel:

```
    loadoutAdvWeaponPanels = new JPanel[4][4];
    loadoutAdvWeaponButtons = new JButton[4];
    loadoutAdvPistolLabels = new JLabel[4][8];

    //Init loadoutAdvPanels[0]

    loadoutAdvWeaponButtons[0] = new JButton("Pistols");

    loadoutAdvPistolLabels[0][0] = new JLabel("USP-S");
    loadoutAdvPistolLabels[0][1] = new JLabel("P2000");
    loadoutAdvPistolLabels[0][2] = new JLabel("Dual Berettas");
    loadoutAdvPistolLabels[0][3] = new JLabel("P250");
    loadoutAdvPistolLabels[0][4] = new JLabel("Five-SeveN");
    loadoutAdvPistolLabels[0][5] = new JLabel("CZ75-Auto");
    loadoutAdvPistolLabels[0][6] = new JLabel("Desert Eagle");
    loadoutAdvPistolLabels[0][7] = new JLabel("R8 Revolver");

    loadoutAdvWeaponPanels[0][0].add(loadoutAdvPistolLabels[0][0]);
```

The error occurs in the last line, but i dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

you should initialize the array `loadoutAdvWeaponPanels`

```
    loadoutAdvWeaponPanels = new JPanel[4][4];
    for(int i = 0; i < loadoutAdvWeaponPanels.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < loadoutAdvWeaponPanels[i].length; j++)
            loadoutAdvWeaponPanels[i][j] = new JPanel();
```

**or** just initialize what you need

```
    loadoutAdvWeaponPanels[0][0] = new JPanel();
    loadoutAdvWeaponPanels[0][0].add(loadoutAdvPistolLabels[0][0]);
```

Comment: use a generic for loop!

Comment: yup, thanks, didnt see that i still needed to initialize the panel and not only the array...

Answer (score 0):

Simple as I see!

You do not initialisized `loadoutAdvWeaponPanels[0][0]`

I prefer to use this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < loadoutAdvWeaponPanels.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; loadoutAdvWeaponPanels[i].length; j++) {
    {
         loadoutAdvWeaponPanels[i][j] = new JPanel();
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, just saw it as well, sorry...